# How to stream data concurrently for multiple requests in node js?

Tags: node.js, node-mysql, exceljs, node-streams, nodejs-stream

I am using node for server side and mysql for databse. I want to make a download functionality which gives user an option to download 1 million records in an .xlsx file. As the data size is too large , i had to go for streaming solution. But when multiple user make a download request , file for only the first user is getting downloaded , rest other requests show a download failure due to network error.

here is the route handler code :-

```
app.get('/download_file',(req,res) => {

  res.writeHead(200, {
    'Content-Disposition': 'attachment; filename="file.xlsx"',
    'Transfer-Encoding': 'chunked',
    'Content-Type': 'application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet'
  });

  let workbook = new Excel.stream.xlsx.WorkbookWriter({ stream: res });
  let worksheet = workbook.addWorksheet('some-worksheet');

  let str = db.query('SELECT * FROM test_data_xl').stream();
  str.on('data', function (d) {
    worksheet.addRow(Object.values(d)).commit(); // format object if required
  });

  str.on('end', function () {
      worksheet.commit();
      workbook.commit();
      console.log('data done');
  });

  str.on('error', function (err) {
      console.log(err);
  });

});
```

And it's just a code for POC.
attached is the screenshot of the failed download.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qEDlD.png)

Comment: I would guess your bottleneck is in the db not in the nodejs itself. Could you verify ? Try to output your nodejs server stats while the request being executed.

Comment: @iwaduarte. I think that too but i read it on google that you can make 151 max concurrent connection to your mysql database server. So , it should work just fine for anything less than 151 .

Comment: on your browser there is a response error while dowloading your files. Could share that here too. My point is could be many things. I am not sure about 151 max concurrent connections when using this orm you are using.  I do not know what the stream() method does. You need to provide more details if you want a more accurate answer